# How to taggenize a plain text with UI

Tags: android, text, view, tags

Given a plain text, I'd like to "taggenize" its words. Does exists a component to do this type of UI? For instance, I want to take a text like "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit" and create a view like bellow:

[image]

I've searched a little and failed to find a short/easy implementation. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I'm doing this by creating a ViewGroup and populating it with customized buttons. For now, it sounds the best and easiest way. A preliminary pseudo-code is:

```
View view = findViewById(someId);
foreach (word in theText) {
   Button bt = new button(word); // a new button, with "word" as label
   view.addView(bt);
}
```